# Can't see files in project explorer in Eclipse android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm working on an Android project. Something happened with my Eclipse project and I can no longer "see" any of my source files in the project explorer. The project explorer only shows :

*src* (clicking and trying to open yields nothing -- I can right click and open in a new window and see a bit more, but still can't decend the directory and see files)

*gen*

*android.jar*

*usb.jar*

*maps.jar*

My java files are still in the directory.

It looks like the project is corrupted somehow?  I have tried deleting everything in `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources` per some suggestions I've found but that doesn't seem to fix it. I created a new test project and it looked ok last night when I created it, although now, it to shows the same behavior as above. I'm using eclipse indigo service release 1. See the image bellow:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you have the wrong view open. Try to open the `Package Explorer`

```
Window > Show View > Package Explorer
```

Comment: Thank you.  Knew it had to be something simple.